# The procedure entry point could not be located in the dynamic link library Core.dll

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2005, singleton, linker

I am converting my project to use DLLs and am trying to break apart my `Singleton` class to avoid using templates.

My class, `LudoMemory`, originally inherited from `Singleton`.  I am trying to give it the functions to destroy and create itself now and have my main engine not rely on the `Singleton`.

I have written a simple destroy method like such:

```
LudoMemory *memory_Singleton = NULL;

    void LudoMemory::Destroy()
    {
        LUDO_SAFE_DELETE(m_Singleton)
    }
```

and upon running the program (no compiler errors) I recieve this error:

> The procedure entry point
>   ?Destroy@LudoMemory@@SAXXZ could not
>   be located in the dynamic link library
>   LudoCore.dll

`LudoCore` is the project that `LudoMemory` belongs to.  Why is this happening?  How can I solve it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you don't have multiple versions of ludocore.dll on your system, do you?
Procedure entry points errors usually mean: you compiled your project against ludocore.lib version x, and when running the program, it uses ludocore.dll version y, and version y does not define LudoMemory::Destroy().

Answer (score 2):

Jacob's answer about multiple DLL versions seems likely.

Also, with some build systems, you must explicitly list which functions will be exported in a DLL.

Research your build environment, and see if you must provide a list of methods to be exported as an entry-point.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio build environment, also you could try by disabling the References in Linker Optimization Settings [ **No(/OPT:NOREF)**]