# Load PNG Images using SDL2.0.3

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, png, sdl-2

I keep getting this error whenever I try to load a PNG image using SDL2.0.3 and visual studio 2012.

```
The procedure entry point inflateReset2 could not be located in the dynamic link library zlib1.dll error
```

I have placed the `slib1.dll` file in the same directory as the .exe, file of my project. I also add it in System32 folder in my windows directory. 
I want to understand what does this error mean, and how to handle it. Thanks in advance!
P.S. The .pmb images work fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After digging more, I found that the version of the slib1.dll in my windows system32 directory is different from the one I copied to my project folder. After replacing the one in the project with the same one from system32 folder, it worked fine. 
I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578950/the-procedure-entry-point-could-not-be-located-in-the-dynamic-link-library-core) on a similar problem really helpful it states that: 
"Procedure entry points errors usually mean: you compiled your project against a library version x, and when running the program, it uses a library.dll version y, and version y does not define library::Destroy()"

Comment: Same issue here, always use the zlib1.dll that came with the sdlimage or image processing library. Don't use the system default one.